# incompatible types: android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener cannot be converted to android.view.View.OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I can not make this button work:

```
public void setConfirmListenner(OnClickListener listener) {
        ((Button) this.contentView.findViewById(R.id.confirmButton)).setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
```

> Error:(296, 85) error: incompatible types:
>   android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener cannot be converted to
>   android.view.View.OnClickListener

Comment: I guess it´s a library you are using because of `setConfirmListener` . Anyway, this is not enough, please show your code and post the complete stacktrace...

Comment: The method holds a `View.OnClickListener` and you are passing a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` . I think you have to delete the import and  import instead `View.OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You literally have to read what the error says: [`View.OnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) and [`DialogInterface.OnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html) are different interfaces. One obvious workaround is to change signature of your `setConfirmListenner` to be

```
public void setConfirmListenner(View.OnClickListener listener) {
```

If this is not what logically happens i.e. `setConfirmListenner` is actually in the class that inherits from [`DialogInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html) which looks quite plausible given your error, you need to create a wrapper. Something like this would probably work:

```
public void setConfirmListenner(final OnClickListener listener) {
    ((Button) this.contentView.findViewById(R.id.confirmButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onClick(MyDialogClass.this, BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        }
    });
}
```

where **`MyDialogClass`** is the name of your custom dialog class. I assume that you want to pass [`BUTTON_POSITIVE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON_POSITIVE) as `which` but you might pass something else if that suits you better.

Comment: You are a great developer, I worked perfectly, thank you very much for the help 